# Add Bootstrap panel with border and centralized text

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create two panels in bootstrap with centralized text and different fonts in the text. Like the image below

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <p>
                Collected This Quarter <br>
                <b>$8084</b>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <p>
                Average Property Income YTD <br>
                <b>$16,985</b>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, my output is:

[image]

How can I have the "shadow" outside the panels and the text inside in similar font to the image above?

Thanks you

Comment: Where did you get that image from? Just get the styles from it.

Comment: I don't have the link for the image. Just a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used to face this problem. So, here is the workaround.

- Add the top-level child divs and give them padding (like `p-1`). This is their only job.
- Within each top-level div, add your `cell's` main content, and style them however you want.

This is the code

```
<div class="parent row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 p-1">
      <div class="shadow-sm text-center child">
          <p class="p-0 m-0">
              Collected This Quarter <br>
              <b>$8084</b>
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 p-1">
      <div class="shadow-sm text-center child">
        <p class="p-0 m-0">
          Average Property Income YTD <br>
              <b>$16,985</b>
          </h4>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Normally I reset padding and margins for `.row` and `.col` classes

```
<style>
  .row, .col-lg-6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
  }
  .child {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .parent {
    background-color: #F3F4F5;
  }
</style>
```

The result is like this
[image]
NOTE: I've used `bg-dark` and `bg-light` classes for showing the background colors of parent and child divs. You can give them whichever color you want.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm doing

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it set a black border. I was trying to apply a shadow effect like in the image from the post

Comment: You can use bootstrap shadow classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/shadows/

Comment: As far as the shadow, the image you provided is small to notice fine details. Moreover, the actual question was about giving spacing to the cells. Regarding shadow, please provide a clearer image and post as a new question.

Comment: If my updated solution answers the main question, please don't forget to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this, used `.panel-body` wrapper

https://jsfiddle.net/420gwtLz/7/

I will suggest using the latest version of Bootstrap, you will get utility classes for shadow and spacing.